# kafka server split into slots

Tags: apache-kafka

In term of splitting the traffic inside a kafka server,
what are the different options ?

```
 1) Split the traffic into different topics.

 2) Split the traffic into different partitions, after being assigned a topic.

 3) Split the traffic into different slots (am not this exist).
```

Thanks

Comment: I have heard of first 2 but AFAIK slots are for flink and flink kafka connector and not exactly for kafka server/broker.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no slot in Kafka server/broker ?

Comment: Yes as per documentation available.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: Not sure I understand your question exactly.

> 1) Split the traffic into different topics.
>   2) Split the traffic into different partitions, after being assigned a topic.

Assuming your question is how to *write* messages into different topics and so on:

- You can use the Kafka producer client for this.
- You also have the option of using Kafka Connect.

> 3) Split the traffic into different slots (am not this exist).

What do you mean?  There are no "slots" in Kafka.